# Given that the closed-form ridge regression solution is $\hat{\beta}_{ridge} = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$, show that ridge outputs correlations

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, ridge-regression

Given that the closed-form ridge regression solution is $\hat{\beta}_{ridge} = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$, show that ridge regression outputs are equal to the correlations used in correlation screening when $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. I understand that as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$, $\beta \rightarrow 0$, which implies that $Y = X \beta + \varepsilon$, so $Y = \varepsilon$. However, I feel like this is not the right track, since I believe $\varepsilon$ reflects the random variance from the individual data points and not the correlations. Any help/direction towards the solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean $\beta \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: yup sorry will edit that

Comment: Could you explain what "correlation screening" is?

Comment: Correlation screening is just calculating correlations between each feature and the dependent variable for feature selection. The idea is, if features are uncorrelated with the dependent variable, you drop the feature from training

Comment: Just to be clear, the above closed form solution assumes that $X$ does *not* include the intercept.

Comment: Let's ignore that such "correlation screening" works poorly.  More to the point, what you want to prove is not generally true.  It sounds like you are assuming $X$ and $Y$ are mean-centered.  Moreover, it's clear that as $\lambda\to \infty,$ all the ridge estimates go to *zero,* because all the other terms remain finite, making the expression $O(1/\lambda).$

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to obtain a general form for the variance matrix of the ridge-estimator, which holds for all penalty parameters $\lambda$.  This is not necessary for your present purposes, but I will do it anyway so that you can see a more general form of the present results.  To start with, the ridge-estimator can be written in terms of the underlying regression coefficient and error vector as:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}(\lambda)
&= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{Y}) \\[6pt]
&= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} (\mathbf{x} \boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) \\[6pt]
&= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) \boldsymbol{\beta} + (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

As $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ we get the asymptotic equivalence:

$$(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \sim \frac{\mathbf{I}}{\lambda} 
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}(\lambda) \sim \frac{(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) \boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}{\lambda}.$$

---

**Variance and correlation:** The variance matrix for the ridge estimator is given by:

$$\begin{align}
V(\lambda, \mathbf{x}) 
&\equiv \mathbb{V}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}(\lambda) | \mathbf{x}) \\[6pt]
&= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbb{V}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) ((\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T})^\text{T} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{I} ((\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T})^\text{T} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) ((\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1})^\text{T} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^6} \bigg( \lambda^2 \mathbf{I} - \lambda (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) - (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^2 \bigg) (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) \bigg( \lambda^2 \mathbf{I} - \lambda (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) - (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^6} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^4 \mathbf{I} - \lambda^3 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) - \lambda^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^2 \\
- \lambda^3 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) + \lambda^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^2 + \lambda (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^3 \\
- \lambda^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^2 + \lambda (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^3 + (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^4 \\
\end{bmatrix} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^6} [ \lambda^4 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) - 2 \lambda^3 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^2 - \lambda^2 (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^3  + 2 \lambda (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^4 + (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^5 ]. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

As $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ you have the asymptotic equivalence:

$$V(\lambda, \mathbf{x}) \sim V^*(\lambda, \mathbf{x}) \equiv \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^2} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}),$$

which has elements:

$$V_{i,j}^*(\lambda, \mathbf{x}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^2} \sum_k x_{i,k} x_{j,k}.$$

Consequently, the asymptotic correlation between any two elements of the ridge-estimator is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Corr}(\hat{\beta}_i, \hat{\beta}_j |\mathbf{x}) 
\sim \frac{\sum_k x_{i,k} x_{j,k}}{\sqrt{(\sum_k x_{i,k} x_{i,k})(\sum_k x_{j,k} x_{j,k})}}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 for a nice analysis.  But it's worth re-emphasizing that the *stated* question is altogether different from this result!

Comment: @whuber: Perhaps I've misunderstood the question --- my reading is that OP wants to know the asymptotic correlation between the estimators as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$.  Is that wrong?

Comment: It comes down to how you interpret "ridge regression outputs." Ordinarily, the maximal "output" of a ridge regression is the ridge trace plot (graphing the coefficient estimates against $\lambda$).  It does not include any kind of covariance matrix as far as I know.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in @Ben's response.  I believe applying Woodbury to $$
(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} + \lambda I)^{-1}
$$ Should yield $$
(x^Tx + \lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda}(I - \frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{x}^T(I + \frac{\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T}{\lambda})^{-1}\mathbf{x})$$
Rather than 
$$
(x^Tx + \lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda}(I - \frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{x}^T(I + \frac{\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T}{\lambda})\mathbf{x})
$$

As stated. So I do not believe it is possible to get rid of the inverse, at least as presented.

Comment: @Nate: Nicely spotted Nate!  I've removed the erroneous part.